# How to grep specific lines and print only those that match character

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a number of pdb files and I want to grep only those lines that starts with `^FORMUL` and if line has `C` followed by the number that is larger then (C3,C4,C5,C6 etc) then I should not print it.

I used this one for extracting line that start with `FORMUL` but don't know how to search trough each of the lines and match it with C followed by 3>.

`grep ^FORMUL *pdb` (probably here have to put some kind of cutoff that if inside each line C3> is found then don't print it).

```
3OC2.pdb:FORMUL   3  HOH   *207(H2 O)    (print it)                                     
3OC7.pdb:FORMUL   2  SF4    FE4 S4       (print it)                                                
3OC8.pdb:FORMUL   3  NIC    C5 H7 N O7   (don't print, there is C5)                                               
3OC9.pdb:FORMUL   4  HOH   *321(H2 O)    (print it)                                                
3OC10.pdb:FORMUL   3  HEM    2(C34 H32 FE N4 O4)  (don't print, there is C34)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use two greps:

```
grep '^FORMUL' *pdb | grep -vE 'C([3-9]|[12][0-9])'
```

The first lists the lines matching `^FORMUL`, the second removes (`-v` inverts the match) those matching `C` followed by a digit between 3 and 9, or two digit numbers beginning with 1 or 2 (so every number from greater than 3 will be removed).

Comment: SInce I am new and cannot vote for useful answers I have to thank You here. Just one thing, since I have many exampels of C10-99 this command  wont keep them but I want to keep them as well. Can I select somehow that if it meets C3-C99 range then print them?

Comment: See if the updated command helps

Comment: Yeah, it is fine now. Thank You very much. All the best!

Comment: Hey, one thing. I figure out that this code will delete all the lines in which it founds C followed by the number 2 or more..in my input file this can be found as well:                                                        
                                                      
3OC7.pdb:FORMUL      2          EDO         C2 H6 O2

Comment: and I want to keep it, anyway, can I modify this script so that whenever it match C3>, but only in the forth column then delete this line? Or if the column is considered how many spaces it has, then from the fourth column till the end?

Comment: @djordje do you need the filename in the output?

Comment: No, with the output I will just grep 3rd column that is in this example EDO.. I will change my example in the question so to clarify..

Comment: @djordje then it's probably simpler to just remove the filename from the output: `grep -h '^FORMUL' *pdb | ...`

Comment: Haha, yes..my mindset sucks..sorry mate for interuption and thank once again :)

Comment: muru: is it possible to put two conditions that: 1. Remove all lines where after C number is grater then 3 (which we did) 2. To put a condition that each line should have at least 6 heavy atoms whic means that N+C+O =6, so that the lines which has C3 N1 01 will be remove as well, is it possible? I tried it in perl but these lines are sooo diverse so I am not sure is it possible. MAny thanks

Comment: @djordje that is way too complex for grep. You should use awk, perl or something similar. And this is well beyond the current question, so post a new question, please (don't edit this one).

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
awk '/^FORMUL/ && !match($4, /C[3-9]?[0-9]/) {print;}' *.pdb
```

?: have an online data source we could try?

*ref(page 154): ftp://ftp.wwpdb.org/pub/pdb/doc/format_descriptions/Format_v33_A4.pdf*